# How do I resolve Error in starting MongoDB

Tags: windows, mongodb

Please I need help
I installed MongoDB on my windows 10 now I learnt that to start the service you'll have to enter a command

cd://user/MongoDB/service/4.4.2/bin>
mongod

But it brought tons of errors
And I also tried this command

cd://user/MongoDB/service/bin> mongo

It's didn't work and kept bringing more errors
Please I need help

Comment: Including your specific errors in the post would be helpful.

Comment: Simply reads the "tons of errors" - actually most of them is just information, you should find the error line.

Comment: Even without knowing the error: Did you create the data directory, i.e. `dbPath`

Comment: `mongod` is the MongoDB service. Without running this, the database is "offline". `mongo` is a shell (i.e. a client application) which connects to the Mongo database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps
Make sure that you added the `<MONGODB_PATH>\bi`n directory to the system variable PATH and run cmd as administrator
Then execute:

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongod --remove
```

Then execute

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongod --dbpath=C:\mongodb --logpath=C:\mongodb\log.txt --install
```

After that right there in the command prompt execute:

```
services.msc
```

And look for MongoDB service and click start.

Done